# How to implement the aliasing constructor by own for my own shared_ptr implementation?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I am trying to implement the shared ptr template class by own.

The prototype for aliasing constructor of `shared_ptr` is

```
template< class Y >
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, element_type *ptr );
```

I have implemented the conversion constructor as follows,

```
shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<U> &p_ownershipObj,T* p_managedObjPtr)
      { 
         if(p_ownershipObj.m_refCountPtr) // Ql
         {
            m_managedObjectPtr=p_managedObjPtr;
            m_refCountPtr = p_ownershipObj.m_refCountPtr;
            m_refCountPtr->m_strongReferenceCount++;            
         }
      }
```

Q1. How to access the `m_refCountPtr` of `shared_ptr<U>`  here?
`m_refCountPtr` is private member of `shared_ptr` template class. I know private member cannot be accessed then how compilers have probably implemented this feature?

Comment: confused about your `shared_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`. Private members can be accessed in class scope and in friends scope: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend

Comment: @Raxvan Yes It can be accessed in class scope. I have two different classes here one is shared_ptr<T>(Which I am going to instantiate) and shared_ptr<U>(which I am passing as argument). Logically it is not same class

Comment: @Raxvan How to achieve firend for template class?

Comment: check the link in the comment, `template <class> friend class shared_ptr;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost solves this problem by either using template member friends or making the members public, depending on the value of the define `BOOST_NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATE_FRIENDS`.

For example the friend declaration looks like this:

```
template<class Y> friend class shared_ptr;
template<class Y> friend class weak_ptr;
```

Comment: `Y` in `<class Y>` not really needed, preferably without `Y` in this case to avoid problem in case you really have `Y` as another template argument in class declaration